# How to tell TypeScript compiler that this module is defined here?

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, tsconfig

I have this local TypeScript file, that when deployed, ends up in the `/opt` directory of my server. So if the file is located at `layers/websocketapi/DataSender.ts` locally, it gets deployed to `opt/DataSender.js`.
However, as I am developing this project locally, it's not in my opt directory so Typescript complains that it can't find this module. However, if I change it to reference the local version, then my deployments break since it's no longer referencing the `/opt` directory where it is actually located on the server.

If I use a `// @ts-ignore` comment, the error goes away, but then I don't get the type support and it assumes a type of `any`.

Here is my code:

```
import { APIGatewayEvent } from 'aws-lambda';
// @ts-ignore
import DataSender from '/opt/DataSender';

export async function handler(event: APIGatewayEvent) {
  const dataSender = new DataSender();
  await dataSender.sendData(event.requestContext.connectionId!, { message: 'hi!' })
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: 'Game created'
  }
}
```

How can I tell the Typescript compiler that this file I'm importing from the opt directory is actually located at `layers/websocketapi/DataSender.js`, but don't change the import statement?

Comment: You can copy your layer folder to your `/opt` folder in your local computer, or create a script to do that.

Comment: Try experimenting with your tsconfig settings. Mainly `baseUrl` and `paths`.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue, any updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `paths` mapping to your `tsconfig.json` file to map the import path `/opt/*` to the real path `layers/websocketapi/*`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "/opt/*": ["layers/websocketapi/*"]
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Paths are resolved relative to `baseUrl`, more information about the path mapping can be found on the typescript documentation https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping